# Chaining yadcf multi_select filters together

Tags: yadcf

Is there a way to chain filters together where by filters applied in one column will pre-filter the available filters in other columns?  Primarily I'm interested in this from a multi_select standpoint, but it could be universal to all filters types I guess.

For example:

Column 1's data contains:

1. Oklahoma
2. Missouri
3. Utah
4. Texas
5. Kansas

Column 2's data contains:

1. Obama
2. Romney

From the dataset I know that all Column 1 data that has 'Oklahoma' will always mean that Column 2 will equal 'Romney'.  Thus, if I select 'Oklahoma' from a mutli_select, then the drop down for the multi_select for Column 2 should now only show 'Romney'.

Basically, can I pre-filter my filters based on other filters already put in place?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about the `cumulative_filtering: true` option of yadcf,

See the [showcase page](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/cumulative_filtering.html) and here a code sample:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';

    var oTable;
    oTable = $('#example').DataTable();

    yadcf.init(oTable,
        [
            {
                column_number : 0,
                filter_type: "multi_select",
                select_type: 'select2'
            }, 
            {
                column_number: 3,
                filter_type: "auto_complete",
                text_data_delimiter: ","
            },
            {
                column_number : 4,
                filter_type: "multi_select",
                select_type: 'select2',
                column_data_type: "html",
                html_data_type: "text",
                filter_default_label: "Select tag"
            }
        ],
        {
            cumulative_filtering: true
        }
    );
});
```

As you see the `cumulative_filtering: true` is an object property, an object that that is a third argument of the `init` function, when using the `.yadcf([{...}])` api you should pass that object as a second arument to the `.yadcf` constractor, like this:

`.yadcf([{...}],  {cumulative_filtering: true})`

Comment: Thanks.  This didn't work for me right out of the gate.  I'm using external filters in conjunction with the Chosen plugin so i'm not sure if that contributed to my issues using this or not.  After tracing what was going on, when you are calling AppendFilters in line 3250 it was going back through and doing everything it needed to except it wasn't actually updating the 'chosen' drop down.  Therefore in line 3250 i inserted a call to destoryThirdPartyPlugins to clean out the 'chosen' drop down and then this worked.

Comment: Good, you found a bug, feel free to open a new issue on github with the details.